# Scala Spark: How to convert an Array[(String,String,String)] to Map[String,Map[String,String]]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I would like to convert an array of **(String,String,String)** to **Map[String,Map[String,String]]**.

Example :

**Input**

```
val inputArray: Array[(String,String,String)] = Array(("elem1","elem2","elem3"),("elem4","elem5","elem6"))
```

**Desired output**

```
val outputMap: Map[String, Map[String, String]] = Map(
 ("elem1", Map("elem2" -> "elem3")),
 ("elem4", Map("elem5" -> "elem6"))
)
```

Comment: And what is the logic behind the conversion? Do you want to group all other tuples by the first element? Or will each tuple create a single map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `Map("elem2" -> "elem3")` is not a good choice in this case, tuples would be better as far as I can reason about (if it holds only on key-value as it is in your question). Anyway, you need to iterate over the array, and update a state of type `Map[String, Map[String, String]]`, just like this:

```scala
inputArray.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Map[String, String]]) {
    case (updatingMap, (elem, key, value)) => 
      updatingMap.updated(elem, Map(key -> value))
  }
```

Also, the question is not about spark right now, unless you explicitly declare where it relates to spark or you may want to solve your issue using spark apis over a dataframe.